# How do I read different input formats from scanner in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, input

I am new Kotlin learner in JetBrainsAcademy. I want to know how can I read different input formats by using `Scanner` class in one code. Before I used Scanner only for simple input format, i.e.:

1)`triangle
  a
  b
  c`

But now I need to solve the problem with three kinds of formats simultaneously(4 data, 3 data and 2 data [my homework page](https://hyperskill.org/learn/step/4606), i.e.:

1)`triangle
  a
  b
  c`

2)`rectangle
 a
 b`

3)`circle
 r`

Of course code below doesn't work. What have I to implement for reading of different input formats?

```
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)

    val typeOfRoom = scanner.next()
    val a = scanner.nextDouble()
    val b = scanner.nextDouble()
    val c = scanner.nextDouble()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`when`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) operator like this:

```
import java.util.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val scanner = Scanner(System.`in`)

    when (scanner.next()) {
        "triangle" -> {
            val a = scanner.nextDouble()
            val b = scanner.nextDouble()
            val c = scanner.nextDouble()
            //do smth
        }
        "rectangle" -> {
            val a = scanner.nextDouble()
            val b = scanner.nextDouble()
            //do smth
        }
        "circle" -> {
            val r = scanner.nextDouble()
            //do smth
        }
    }
}
```